# Is there an alarm-clock / timer for Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: unity, 13.10, time, clock

I'd like to use a timer / alarm-lock for Ubuntu 13.10, that appears next to or within the dropdom-menu of the clock in the top-Panel.

I tried e.g. "gnome-shell-timer", "alarm-clock", but both seem not to work within the unity desktop environment (and result in system crashes).

Is there not timer for unity available?

Comment: What happens when you open ubuntu software center and search for clock and for alarm? You should at least find these: https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/search/?q=CLOCK&op=  and https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/search/?q=ALARM&op=

Comment: Going by rating: https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gpe-clock/ and https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/alarm-clock-applet/

Answer (score 1):

Timer applet is what I reccomend. It does have a limit of 48 hours the exact program name is Timer-applet Another one is Alarm-clock alarm clock is less limited and it is the best choice. Also there is a widget here (http://www.toggl.com/public/widgets) This is a similar post to another.